# Adding drawables to an ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am having an issue with Mono for Android and adding drawables as background images or image resources in an `ImageView`. I have a file in my drawable folder called `LogoLarge.png`, which I want to display. Its `Build Action` is set to `AndroidResource`. So I try this:

```
<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/Logo"
  android:src="@drawable/LogoLarge"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  />
```

The `LogoLarge` resource is referenced in `Resource.Designer.cs`. Building the project works fine. When I try to deploy to the emulator, I get the following in the build output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Novell\mandroid.exe -v --nosign --sdk-dir="C:\Android" --builddir="C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\obj\Debug\android" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" -S="C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\obj\Debug\res" --package="HelloWorld2.HelloWorld2"   --nolink --abi="armeabi" --java-sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26" --debug --manifest-template="C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" --sdk-platform="8" "C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\bin\Debug\HelloWorld2.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.2\Mono.Android.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
monodroid : error 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\HelloWorld2.csproj]
    at MonoDroid.Utils.ProcessRocks+<ReadStandardOutput>c__Iterator5.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeCommand (IEnumerable`1 commandLine) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Toolbox.InvokeAapt (System.String packageName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreatePackagedResources (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 javaTypes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.Droidinator.CreateApk () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Monodroid.MainClass.Main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Vegard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HelloAndroid\HelloWorld2\HelloWorld2.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

If I remove the `android:src` property from the XML file, and put this in my `Activity1.cs` file, it works:

```
ImageView i = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Logo);
i.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.LogoLarge);
```

The same issue also occurs when trying to set a background image for any view using `android:background="@drawable/SomeBackground"` in XML, but works fine when doing it programmatically.

What is happening here. Is this a bug in MonoDroid?

Comment: check your avd any thing odd ?>

Comment: This is with a standard Hello World app (a blank app created using Visual Studio 2010), and this application works well. It is only when I try to add any drawable in the layout XML file it crashes. The AVD is working fine.

Comment: I don't think you could put images/resources that use caps in their file names. Try changing LogoLarge.png to logolarge.png and see if it works.

Comment: Kumar Bibek: You were right. Renaming the resource to lowercase (and all references to it) solved the problem. Very confusing then that `Icon.png`, which is included by default, has a capital `I` at the beginning. Turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it... :)

Comment: This is a bug in `mandroid`'s resource renaming logic. Please file a bug at bugzilla.xamarin.com so that we can fix this in a future release.

Comment: This should be fixed in the next release (1.0.21316 or later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your LogoLarge must be logolarge , because you only can use lower case letters in the drawables.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is so? It does not appear to be an Android restriction, but more of a restriction for Monodroid.

Comment: It is in the eclipse and in other IDEs too, like IDEAJ and other. The drawable file mustn't contain upper-case letters :) In other mode you will get the Invalid file name error.

Comment: Except `mandroid.exe` will modify AndroidResource files to lowercase resource names. The intent is to allow developers to use consistent resource casing, while still fitting within Android's "everything must be lowercase" requirements.